# Resize li without changing other li positions

Tags: javascript, css

I have a list of buttons whose onclick functions make an effect on a list of p items. Function 3 and Function 5 change the font-size of the corresponding p elements, causing the other p's to get pushed away from their original positions. I would like to prevent this to keep the p's how they appear initially. Thanks in advance. https://github.com/jusselman/clickFun

```js
function myFunction() {
  var el = document.getElementById("topTitle");

  if (el.style.transform === "translateY(350px)" && el.style.color === "blue" && el.style.fontSize === "54px") {
    el.style.transform = "translateY(0px)";
    el.style.color = "black";
    el.style.fontSize = "32px";
    el.style.transition = "all 1s linear";
  } else {
    el.style.transform = "translateY(350px)"
    el.style.transition = "all 1s linear";
    el.style.color = "blue";
    el.style.fontSize = "54px";
  }
};

function myFunction1() {
  var el1 = document.getElementById("display1");

  if (el1.style.opacity === "1") {
    el1.style.transition = "opacity 1s linear";
    el1.style.opacity = "0";
  } else {
    el1.style.transition = "opacity 1s linear";
    el1.style.opacity = "1";
  }
};

function myFunction2() {
  var el2 = document.getElementById("display2");

  if (el2.style.opacity === "0") {
    el2.style.transition = "opacity 1s linear";
    el2.style.opacity = "1";
  } else {
    el2.style.transition = "opacity 1s linear";
    el2.style.opacity = "0";
  }
}

function myFunction3() {
  var el3 = document.getElementById("display3");

  if (el3.style.fontSize === "40px") {
    el3.style.transition = "font-size 1s linear";
    el3.style.fontSize = "16px";
  } else {
    el3.style.transition = "font-size 1s linear";
    el3.style.fontSize = "40px";
  }
}

function myFunction4() {
  var el4 = document.getElementById("display4");
  // el3.style.transition = "transform 1s linear";
  // el3.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";

  if (el4.style.transform === "rotate(180deg)") {
    el4.style.transition = "transform 1s linear";
    el4.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
  } else {
    el4.style.transition = "transform 1s linear";
    el4.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
  }

}

function myFunction5() {
  var el5 = document.getElementById("display5");
  // el3.style.transition = "transform 1s linear";
  // el3.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";

  if (el5.style.transform === "translate(500px)") {
    el5.style.transition = "transform 1s linear";
    el5.style.transform = "translate(0)";
  } else {
    el5.style.transition = "transform 1s linear";
    el5.style.transform = "translate(500px)";
  }

}

function myFunction5() {
  var el5 = document.getElementById("display5");

  if (el5.style.transform === "translateX(450px) rotate(360deg)" && el5.style.fontSize === "80px") {
    el5.style.transition = "all 1s linear";
    el5.style.transform = "translatex(0) rotate(0)";
    el5.style.fontSize = "16px";
  } else {
    el5.style.transition = "all 1s linear";
    el5.style.transform = "translateX(450px) rotate(360deg)";
    el5.style.fontSize = "80px";


  }

}

function myFunction6() {
  var el6 = document.getElementById("display6");

  if (el6.style.transform === "translate(250px) rotate(360deg)") {
    el6.style.transition = "transform 1s linear";
    el6.style.transform = "translate(0) rotate(0)"
  } else {
    el6.style.transition = "transform 1s linear";
    el6.style.transform = "translate(250px) rotate(360deg)";


  }

}
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blackBoard img {
  /* height: 500px;
  width: 500px; */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  /* background-image: url("../img/mirror.jpg"); */
}

h1.title {
  text-align: center;
  /* top: 25%; */
  height: 550px;
  color: black;
}

ul.buttons {
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  /* margin-top: 500px; */
  top: 25%;
  left: 16%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}

li {
  display: block;
}

button.effects {
  height: 30px;
  width: 90px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 10%;
  color: white;
}

#display1 {
  opacity: 0;
}

#display2 {
  opacity: 1;
}

#display3 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

p.textDisplay {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.texts {
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  /* margin-top: 500px; */
  top: 24%;
  left: 22%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Shine</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="title" id="topTitle">The onclick Event</h1>

  <div class="blackBoard">
    <img src="img/mirror.png">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="buttons">
        <li>
          <button onclick="myFunction()" class="effects">Move Title</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button onclick="myFunction1()" class="effects">Function 1</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button onclick="myFunction2()" id="btn2" class="effects">Function 2</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button onclick="myFunction3()" id="btn3" class="effects">Function 3</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button onclick="myFunction4()" id="btn4" class="effects">Function 4</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button onclick="myFunction5()" id="btn5" class="effects">Function 5</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button onclick="myFunction6()" id="btn6" class="effects">Function 6</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="text-container">
      <ul class="texts">
        <li>
          <p id="display1" class="textDisplay">Display #1</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p id="display2" class="textDisplay">Display #2</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p id="display3" class="textDisplay">Display #3</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p id="display4" class="textDisplay">Display #4</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p id="display5" class="textDisplay">Display #5</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p id="display6" class="textDisplay">Display #6</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First, why do you have two functions called `myFunction5`? Second, it would be easier for everyone if you would put this into a code snippet. Just edit your code, hit Ctrl-M, and I think you can figure it out from there. Finally, it would be best if you would remove any irrelevant code (e.g. your title markup) from the sample, so we don't have to spend time figuring out what code is relevant and what code isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of animating `font-size` you can animate `scale` to increase the size of the text without affecting the position of anything else on the page. Example code in snippet:

```js
// var  elTrans = style.transition;
// var opac1 = "opacity 1s linear";
function myFunction() {
  var el = document.getElementById("topTitle");

  if(el.style.transform === "translateY(350px)" && el.style.color === "blue" && el.style.fontSize === "54px") {
    el.style.transform = "translateY(0px)";
    el.style.color = "black";
    el.style.fontSize = "32px";
    el.style.transition = "all 1s linear";
    } else {
    el.style.transform = "translateY(350px)"
    el.style.transition = "all 1s linear";
    el.style.color = "blue";
    el.style.fontSize = "54px";
   }
};

function myFunction1() {
  var el1 = document.getElementById("display1");

  if(el1.style.opacity === "1") {
    el1.style.transition = "opacity 1s linear";
    el1.style.opacity = "0";
  } else {
    el1.style.transition = "opacity 1s linear";
    el1.style.opacity = "1";
  }
};

function myFunction2() {
  var el2 = document.getElementById("display2");

  if(el2.style.opacity === "0") {
    el2.style.transition = "opacity 1s linear";
    el2.style.opacity = "1";
  } else {
    el2.style.transition = "opacity 1s linear";
    el2.style.opacity = "0";
  }
}

function myFunction3() {
  var el3 = document.getElementById("display3");

  if(el3.style.transform === "scale(2.5)") {
    el3.style.transition = "transform 1s linear";
    el3.style.transform = "scale(1)";
  } else {
    el3.style.transition = "transform 1s linear";
    el3.style.transform = "scale(2.5)";
  }
}

function myFunction4() {
  var el4 = document.getElementById("display4");
  // el3.style.transition = "transform 1s linear";
  // el3.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";

  if(el4.style.transform === "rotate(180deg)") {
    el4.style.transition = "transform 1s linear";
    el4.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
  } else {
    el4.style.transition = "transform 1s linear";
    el4.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
  }

}

function myFunction5() {
  var el5 = document.getElementById("display5");
  // el3.style.transition = "transform 1s linear";
  // el3.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";

  if(el5.style.transform === "translate(500px)") {
    el5.style.transition = "transform 1s linear";
    el5.style.transform = "translate(0)";
  } else {
    el5.style.transition = "transform 1s linear";
    el5.style.transform = "translate(500px)";
  }

}

function myFunction5() {
  var el5 = document.getElementById("display5");

  if(el5.style.transform === "translateX(450px) rotate(360deg) scale(4)") {
    el5.style.transition = "all 1s linear";
    el5.style.transform = "translatex(0) rotate(0) scale(1)";
    } else {
    el5.style.transition = "all 1s linear";
    el5.style.transform = "translateX(450px) rotate(360deg) scale(4)";
  }
}

function myFunction6() {
  var el6 = document.getElementById("display6");

  if(el6.style.transform === "translate(250px) rotate(360deg)") {
    el6.style.transition = "transform 1s linear";
    el6.style.transform = "translate(0) rotate(0)"
    } else {
    el6.style.transition = "transform 1s linear";
    el6.style.transform = "translate(250px) rotate(360deg)";


  }

}
```

```css
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1.title {
  text-align: center;
  height: 550px;
  color: black;
}

ul.buttons {
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  top: 25%;
  left: 16%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  position: absolute;
}

li {
  display: block;
}

button.effects {
  height: 30px;
  width: 90px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 10%;
  color: white;
}


#display1 {
    opacity: 0;
}

#display2 {
    opacity: 1;
}

#display3 {
    font-size: 16px;
}

p.textDisplay {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.texts {
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  top: 34%;
  left: 32%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title" id="topTitle">The onclick Event</h1>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="buttons">
    <li>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="effects">Move Title</button>
  </li>
    <li>
    <button onclick="myFunction1()" class="effects">Function 1</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button onclick="myFunction2()" id="btn2" class="effects" >Function 2</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button onclick="myFunction3()" id="btn3" class="effects">Function 3</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button onclick="myFunction4()" id="btn4" class="effects" >Function 4</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button onclick="myFunction5()" id="btn5" class="effects" >Function 5</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button onclick="myFunction6()" id="btn6" class="effects" >Function 6</button>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="text-container">
  <ul class="texts">
    <li>
      <p id="display1" class="textDisplay">Display #1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p id="display2" class="textDisplay">Display #2</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p id="display3" class="textDisplay">Display #3</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p id="display4" class="textDisplay">Display #4</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p id="display5" class="textDisplay">Display #5</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p id="display6" class="textDisplay">Display #6</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```